# How to fetch data from table having millions of records using spring jdbc template

Tags: java, mysql, java-8, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to fetch data using spring jdbc template.
The table has millions of records.

Using the below code is taking infinite time and finally i have stop running the code.

```
private static final String CLIENTDATA_QUERY = "select logtime, clientip, clientagent, uri from client_data";
public List<ClientDataModel> readFromClientDataDB() {
//      jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(1000);
        List<ClientDataModel> clientData = jdbcTemplate.query(CLIENTDATA_QUERY, new RowMapper<ClientDataModel>() {

            @Override
            public ClientDataModel mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                ClientDataModel model = new ClientDataModel();
                model.setLogtime(rs.getString("logtime"));
                model.setClientIP(rs.getString("clientip"));
                model.setClientAgent(rs.getString("clientagent"));
//              model.setUri(rs.getString("uri"));
                return model;
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Client Data Size :" + clientData.size());
        return clientData;
    }
```

Please can someone suggest how can i retrieve records from a huge table in the most efficient way.

All records are required to be fetched and then the code for further logic begins. This is on server side.

Comment: Paginate, paginate, paginate! Use a cursor, etc.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner please can you suggest what you mean by cursor. Can you also give an example if possible. Thanks

Comment: can't you process the records page by page? Why do you need to first read the whole table into memory?

Comment: And here's an [example of cursor](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-cursor-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a method that returns a list instead use [RowCallBackHandler.](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.0.M1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html)  You can also use Pagination in your query.

JDBCTemplate requires to read in all data retrieved from the database in the form of object, having lots of memory consumption in holding large result set. Spring Batch is a better solution in such scenarios.

Comment: Even using a [RowCallBackHandler](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.0.M1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html) is giving me java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: Have you ever found an ideal solution on this?